# Android Studio Firebase realtime database always denies deleting data

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Every time I try to delete user data from the database, it gets rejected. Could anyone help me how to solve it?

The rules I set are:

```
{
"rules": {
    "admin": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "products": {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
    },
    "users": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('account_role').val() == 'admin'",
        ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('account_role').val() == 'admin'",
        "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    }
}
```

}

My code to delete the data is this:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(userUid);
    databaseReference.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(unused -> Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.data_successful_deleted))).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(DeleteAccountActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDv4R.png)

What I can't understand is why I can create, read and update the data, but I can't delete. I can only delete if I put the rules ".write": true.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error message and the rules, the only conclusion seems to be that the user is not/no longer signed in when you try to delete their data. I recommend always checking that sort of condition in the code with an assertion, for example like this:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(userUid);
if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) throw new AssertionError("Trying to delete user data without a current user");
databaseReference.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(unused -> Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.data_successful_deleted))).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
    Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(DeleteAccountActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
});
```

If you expected the user to be signed in, it might be good to check when they were signed out, for example with an [auth state change listener](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android).

One reason that the user might not be signed in anymore is if you delete the user account, before deleting their data from the database. Deleting an account is a synchronous operation, so you'll want to delete the data from the database **before** deleting the account.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really happening, the login user was being deleted before the user data. It's fixed now thanks to you. I was having nightmares about this, thanks again.